# How to properly encode UTF-8 for JavaScript and JSON?

Tags: php, javascript, json, encoding, utf-8

I have a problem creating an input validation hash. JavaScript submits data to API and API validates the sent data with json_encode. Basically it works like this:

```
$input=array('name'='John Doe','city'=>'New York');
$validationHash=sha1(json_encode($input).$key); // Key is known to both servers
```

If PHP connects to another server, then everything works. It also works through JavaScript (I have a custom sha1() function there as well):

var validationHash=sha1(JSON.stringify({'name':'John Doe','city'=>'New York'})+key);

My problem comes when the string contains UTF-8 characters. For example, if one of the values is:

```
Ränisipelgasöösel
```

Then PHP server that receives the command converts it to this after JSON encoding:

```
R\u00e4nisipelgas\u00f6\u00f6sel
```

I need to do this in JavaScript as well, but I haven't been able to work out how. I need to make sure that I send proper validation hash to the server or the command fails. I found from Google that unescape(encodeURIComponent(string)) and decodeURIComponent() could be used, but neither gives me the same string that PHP has and validates with.

UTF-8 is used on both client and server.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you look for a method how to compare two json strings with each other.

Comment: No. This already works, I am comparing them through hashing. Just that if the characters are different then hashing is also different. I need to be able to convert string to the same one that PHP json_encode() has it after encoding. It's only PHP json_encode() that does this, JSON.stringify(string)!=json_encode($string)

Comment: Have you tried with `json_encode` from the PHPJs project? http://phpjs.org/functions/json_encode:457

Comment: Are you not sending the JSON string for Javascript to PHP or vice versa? In which case, can't you just use the string as received for the hashing, before decoding it?

Comment: @Saxoier — Really? I looked up [codepoint 00f6](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00F6/index.htm)

Comment: @DaveRandom No I am not sending the JSON string itself. I need to calculate a 'hash' from the data that I am sending so that I can validate the data on receiving end. Server gets data correctly and everything is sent as UTF-8 without problems (log files have the input as UTF-8 and PHP json_encode also treats it as UTF-8. It is also UTF-8 on client side. Problem is that JSON.stringify() works differently from json_encode().

Comment: @hakre I'll look into it, but the footprint there seems to be rather heavy. All I need is a way to convert UTF-8 characters to their Unicode encoding just like PHP does it. But I'll look into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not seem to be possible. The only working solution I have found is to encode all data with encodeURIComponent() on browser side and with rawurlencode() on PHP side and then calculate the JSON from these values in arrays.

Answer (score 3):

My fix was to raw url encode my json data like so.

```
rawurlencode( json_encode( $data ) );
```

And then from within javascript decode the raw url encoded json and then parse the json string like so.

```
JSON.parse( decodeURIComponent( data ) );
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Why not base64 encode the data for safe transport? It encodes UTF-8 characters in a safe string that can be sent across different mediums - php, javascript etc. That way you can base64 decode the string at the receiving end. Voila!

By base64 encoding the data, i mean base64 encoding the values and not the whole json string

Comment: Actually that's no good, JavaScript doesn't have a working base64 converter either, it's just as bad. The one from php.js also throws errors in latest Chrome.

Comment: @kristovaher then just add a custom base64 library? http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-base64.html

Comment: Ränisipelgasöösel is UsOkbmlzaXBlbGdhc8O2w7ZzZWw= after base64 encoding

Comment: It is, but it doesn't work in the situation I am using it. I looped that function through values in my object and it threw an error. But I found a solution without having to include that function. I will use encodeURIComponent() on Javascript side and rawurlencode() on PHP side.

Answer (score -3):

is you html page encoding utf-8?

> `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">`

Comment: The problem is that two JSON serializers are choosing to represent characters in different (but valid) ways. The encoding of the document is irrelevant.

Comment: Quentin is correct. And yes, document is UTF-8 in both tag as well as file format itself as well as server.