# Non English text are converting into junk values

Tags: android

In my project am working on `json` to receive and send response to a server. Its working fine for `English` letters.

Now the problem is when am used non English letters(Telugu,Tamil, or Hindi) are automatically converted into junk values(`??????????`) in sever side database.

Sample method calling server:

```
        AsyncHttpClient mNewCaller = new AsyncHttpClient();
        mNewCaller.setTimeout(DEFAULT_TIMEOUT);

        final ProgressDialog mpd = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
        mpd.setTitle("Please wait");
        mpd.setMessage("Signing in");
        mpd.setCancelable(false);
        RequestParams mParams = new RequestParams();
        mParams.add(Constants.JSON_HEADER, obj1.toString());
        mParams.add(Constants.JSON_BODY, obj2.toString());
        // Pref.setValue(getApplicationContext(), Constants.PREF_IMEIID, uid);
        Log.e("login", mParams.toString());
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        View promptView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.device_name, null);
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
        alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptView);
        final EditText code = (EditText) promptView.findViewById(R.id.deviceName);
        alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                authCode = code.getText().toString();
                sendDName(authCode, mContext);
            }
        }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        alertD = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        Constants.EMAIL_ID = email;

        String url = DynamicURL;
        mNewCaller.get(Login.DynamicURL, mParams, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onStart() {
                super.onStart();
                if (mpd != null) {
                    mpd.show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString) {
                super.onSuccess(statusCode, headers, responseString);
                Log.e("frag", responseString + " " + statusCode);
                if (mpd != null) {
                    mpd.dismiss();
                }
                if (responseString.equalsIgnoreCase("NODEVICENAME")) {
                    alertD.show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
                super.onSuccess(statusCode, headers, response);
                Constants.EMAIL_ID = email;
                Log.e("frag", response.toString() + " " + statusCode);
                JSONArray jAry = null;
                if (mpd != null) {
                    mpd.dismiss();
                }
                if (response.has(Constants.STATUS)) {
                    try {
                        if (response.getString(Constants.STATUS).equalsIgnoreCase("TABLOGINFAILED")) {
                            Snack.show(mContext, "Wrong email or password");
                            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong email or password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            return;
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    try {
                        if (response.getString(Constants.STATUS).equalsIgnoreCase("NODEVICENAME")) {
                            alertD.show();
                            return;
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                try {
                    Constants.DEVICE_NAME = response.getString(Constants.DEVICENAME);
                    Constants.CUSTOMER_ID = response.getString("customerid");
                    jAry = response.getJSONArray(Constants.CAMPAIGN_LIST);

                    if (response.has("otpenabled")) {
                        Constants.OTP_ENABLED = response.getBoolean("otpenabled");
                        Constants.OTP_ENABLED = false;
                    }

                    Constants.PREF_JSONARRAY = jAry.toString();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Constants.login = 1;
                intent = new Intent(Login.this, Home.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONArray response) {
                super.onSuccess(statusCode, headers, response);
                Log.e("frag", response.toString() + " " + statusCode);
                if (mpd != null) {
                    mpd.dismiss();
                }
                Log.e("frag", response.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString, Throwable throwable) {
                super.onFailure(statusCode, headers, responseString, throwable);
                Log.e("frag", responseString + " " + statusCode);

                if (statusCode == 500) {

                    //   Snack.show(mContext, "Please try again with a valid email id");
                    new SweetAlertDialog(Login.this, SweetAlertDialog.ERROR_TYPE)
                            .setTitleText("User does not exist")
                            .setContentText("Please try again with a valid email id")
                            .show();

                }

                if (mpd != null) {
                    mpd.dismiss();
                }
                /*if (responseString.equalsIgnoreCase("FALSE")) {
                    alertD.show();
                }*/
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, Throwable throwable, JSONObject errorResponse) {
                super.onFailure(statusCode, headers, throwable, errorResponse);
                Log.e("frag", statusCode + " failed obj");

                try {

                    if (statusCode == 0) {

                        new SweetAlertDialog(Login.this, SweetAlertDialog.ERROR_TYPE)
                                .setTitleText("Server Down")
                                .setContentText("Please try again later")
                                .show();

                    } else if (errorResponse.getString(Constants.STATUS).equalsIgnoreCase("NODEVICENAME")) {
                        alertD.show();
                        return;
                    } else if (errorResponse.getString(Constants.STATUS).equalsIgnoreCase("TABLOGINFAILED")) {
                        // Snack.show(mContext, "Please check your email or password");
                        new SweetAlertDialog(Login.this, SweetAlertDialog.ERROR_TYPE)
                                .setTitleText("Incorrect login details")
                                .setContentText("Please check your email or password")
                                .show();
                    } else {

                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                // Snack.show(mContext, "Wrong email or password");
                if (mpd != null) {
                    mpd.dismiss();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, Throwable throwable, JSONArray
                    errorResponse) {
                super.onFailure(statusCode, headers, throwable, errorResponse);
                Log.e("frag", errorResponse.toString() + " " + statusCode);
                Snack.show(mContext, "Wrong email or password");
                if (mpd != null) {
                    mpd.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to properly encode UTF-8 for JavaScript and JSON?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10142050/how-to-properly-encode-utf-8-for-javascript-and-json)

Comment: show some of your code on  what you are doing on `HttpPost` methods...also check on the server if `UTF-8` is enabled in db

Comment: would you try with `params =  new StringEntity(params, HTTP.UTF_8)`  OR `UrlEncoder.encode(params)`

Comment: letters are changing into junk values in server side database

Comment: which technology being used on server/db

Comment: Java is used in server side